# Is there a website / wiki detailing the banned substances in each country?

Tags: legal, online-resources, food-and-drink, drugs

Some countries/cities allow you to smoke weed.

Some countries ban certain drugs, while others do not.

Some are 'dry' while others are dry (alcohol banned).

I'm familiar with [wikivoyage](http://www.wikivoyage.org), [Hitchwiki](http://hitchwiki.org/en/Main_Page), [TrashWiki](http://trashwiki.org/en/Main_Page) and other such sites, but wondering if one exists for detailing banned/non-banned/decriminalised substances?

Comment: Interesting question. Although outside of the US (and maybe Canada) this would be a country-wide question, rather than city/county/state-wide. The only substance I know that has federal/local restrictions (outside the US/Canada) is alcohol. Allowed in some places and not others (or limited access) in Indonesia, Malaysia, India, etc. Would you include alcohol in your list?

Comment: @dda - Australia has (some) different rules for each state, so I presume some other countries do too :/
Other countries have issues with [certain painkillers](http://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/drugs-medicine-egypt-laura-plummer-tramadol-painkillers-illegal-uae-dubai-abu-dhabi-which-countries-a8038286.html), like codeine.  Yeah I should extend it to alcohol.

Comment: Japan has issues with some medicine that are readily available in the West, too.

Comment: @dda Regional restrictions are not limited to USA and Canada. In Germany, sales hours for alcohol are restricted in some states. Public alcohol consumption can be restricted on municipality level. Drug laws are federal, but their interpretation, e.g. of 'for personal use' (Eigenbedarf), differs significantly from state to state. In some states, posession of smaller amounts of weaker drugs is de facto decriminalized, while the same amount in other states will lead to prosecution.

Comment: Since this is travel, we might assume the "banned" term refers to bringing from a foreign country -- in which case it is federal by default (n countries that are federations), since Customs is national, not local. Sales hours etc are not relevant here I think.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, such a Wiki doesn't exist as of 2017. It is likely that it would never exist as even finding the list of banned substances for a *single* country and keeping it up to date is *a lot* of work, not to mention mapping the forbidden lists across different nomenclatures.

Comment: Screw the work, the legal liability would be horrific...

Comment: Honestly, when you consider all the stuff you find on the Internet, including Wikipedia, Wikivoyage and the like, I don't think the work or the legal liability would stop anyone from attempting it. In fact, it's not limited to this topic or neatly organised with travellers in mind but a lot of material is actually available on the sites I mentioned. So are we sure there isn't anything like that anywhere? How comprehensive or useful it would be is another question…

Comment: @Relaxed AFAIK understanding whether or not you can import e.g. Codeine into any given country as a tourist and what prescription you need for it is a nightmare if you do things by the book. If someone does find a better answer I'll delete mine

Comment: @JonathanReez Of course, I am not arguing with that. But that does not mean nobody tried to create such a list! And there could be plausible ways to deal with this particular problem: for example a "no concern”/"beware, there are special rules”/“forbidden” classification.